# If $y$ is the solution of $\left\{y'=-y+\sqrt{t},y(0)=y_0>0\right\}$, then $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{y(t)}{\sqrt{t}}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, error-function

The homogeneous equation $$y'=-y$$ has the solution $$y_h(t)=ce^{-t}\;\;\;\;\;(c,t\in\mathbb{R})$$ In order to find a particular solution we can take the approach $$y_p(t)\stackrel{!}{=}c(t)e^{-t}$$ Since $$y_p'(t)=c'(t)e^{-t}-c(t)e^{-t}\tag{1}$$ insertion into the differential equation yields $$c'(t)e^{-t}=\sqrt{t}$$ So, we've got

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
c(t) &= \int\sqrt{t}e^tdt \\
     &= 2\int\theta^2e^{\theta^2}d\theta\;\;\;\;\left(\theta=\sqrt{t},\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$\tag{2}$

However, the integral is related to the error function. So, I can't find a closed form for it. The solution to the initial value problem is given by $(1)$ and from $(2)$ we've got an idea how $c$ looks like.

How can we show $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{y(t)}{\sqrt{t}}=1$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need an explicit formula for the integral to compute the limit. According to your calculations, the solution is
$$
y(t)=y_0\,e^{-t}+e^{-t}\int_0^t\sqrt s\,e^s\,ds.
$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{y(t)}{\sqrt t}&=y_0\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt t}+\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt t}\int_0^t\sqrt s\,e^s\,ds\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^t\sqrt s\,e^s\,ds}{e^t\sqrt t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt t\,e^t}{e^t\sqrt t+e^t/(2\,\sqrt t)}\\
&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+1/(2\,t)}\\
&=1.
\end{align}$$
Use has been made of L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks! Corected.